# Unable to shard a mongodb collection with existing index. Getting "couldn't find valid index for shard key"

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a collection with the following index...

```
{ 
    "feedId" : 1, 
    "timekey" : 1, 
    "entity.samplingRate" : 1, 
    "endTimekey" : 1, 
    "geo" : "2dsphere"
}
```

and I'm trying to shard the collection using the following shard key...

```
{
    "feedId": 1,
    "timekey": 1,
    "entity.samplingRate": 1
}
```

which is giving me the following error...

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "couldn't find valid index for shard key",
    "code" : 96,
    ...
}
```

Why doesn't this work? Is it because "geo" is a "2dsphere" index? Or is it because of the "." in "entity.samplingRate"? It is not an index on an array (i.e "entity" is a subobject, not an array). Is there something else going on here?